# perform segue with the same button to two different viewControllers based on information in uitextfield

Tags: swift, segue

I am trying to make my view controller segue to two different view controllers with the same button. But i want the segue's to be done based on information that is in an uitextfield. e.g = if the textfield contains the right information then i will need the segue to perform to segue to viewControllerA if the information does not match my array of strings, ViewController will segue to viewControllerB.

Sample code:

```
@IBOutlet var pcTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var odButton: UIButton!
var activePcText = ["over", "left", "weak", "never"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pcTextField.delegate = self
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    odButton.hidden = true
    self.pcTextField.addTarget(self, action: "pcEmpty", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}


@IBAction func odButton(sender: AnyObject) { }
```

I tried to implement an if statement as..

```
@IBAction func odButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if pcTextField.text!.containsString(activePcText) { }
}
```

I just get an error saying:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'
```

Comment: You do this in your `prepareForSegue` method, you would use an `if-else` statement to determine which view controller is the right one to sege too based on the `UITextField` text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var pcTextField: UITextField!

let activePcText = ["over", "left", "weak", "never"]

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let text = pcTextField.text?.lowercaseString ?? ""
    let destination = activePcText.map { $0.lowercaseString }.contains(text) ? "viewControllerA" : "viewControllerB"

    performSegueWithIdentifier(destination, sender: self)
}
```

This makes it case insensitive.

Comment: Ive been trying to find a solution for the pass 2 days but cannot find one, do you understand what i am trying to do or should i express more?

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell from your question: you want to segue to a view based on the text in your textfield. If the text matches a string in your array, it should segue to `viewControllerA` and if there are no matches `viewControllerB`. That's what my answer does :).

Comment: with the code you provided It segue's to viewControllerA regardless of text in the UITextField..?

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong. Because as you can see in my updated answer, it's working.

Comment: I put your code in my project exactly how you wrote it i don't know what i can be doing wrong? When the button is clicked it segues to viewControllerA regardless of text in textfield...

Comment: I've updated the answer a little bit so you can check if `destination` is `viewControllerA` or `viewControllerB`. Do you have your segue identifiers configured properly? I.e. `viewControllerA` for view controller A and `viewControllerB` for view controller B.

Comment: yes i have the segue identifiers set up, i think it is cause i haven't entered my array of Strings (ActivePcText) can i insert it as the array. or do i have to enter the strings manually..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102820/discussion-between-eendje-and-p-junior).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a `prepareForSegue` method that would accomplish what it sounds like you want to do

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier" {
    if myTextField.text = "words inside text field" {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! MyViewController
    } else if myTextField.text = "different words in text field" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! MyOtherViewController
    }
  }
}
```

So depending on the text inside of `myTextField`, the segue will be performed to either `MyViewController` or `MyOtherViewController`

And then in the `@IBAction` of whichever button you want to trigger the segue you would add `performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier")`

Comment: If he has set up his segue identifiers properly and using my answer, he wouldn't need to override this..

Comment: Yes, yours would work, this would work as well. Just giving the asker some different options so that he may understand there exists more than one way. This may also be an easier version for the asker to read and to understand.

Comment: Thats true, I didn't mean it in any offending way. Just wanted to point out it's  extra (unnecessary) code :).

Comment: No worries :), we are both here to help. I agree, mine is a less "swifty" version !

Comment: In your code where it says           if myTextField.text = "words inside text field" can i not in anyway make it be as  "   if myTextField.text =  activePcText        "

Comment: I am not entirely sure I am understanding you correctly but yes, you can do this.

Comment: in my example `myTextField` is the name of the text field, which in your case is `pcTextField`. And `.text` accesses the text property of the specified text field